# Build angular application for a specific version of IE browser

Tags: angular, webpack-4

We are using Angular 4 to build our application. We are supporting our application on IE Edge and Chrome. Now we have asked to support IE 10 also. For this we plan to create separate build. If there some features in Webpack to support this so that generated build is optimized for IE 10? I mean do we have features/ plugins/ custom plugins in webpack to help us create builds optimized for IE 10.

Comment: why a designated build, whats wrong with polyfills ?

Comment: Right point @Stavm. No idea how webpack treats poly fills.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support